# How to use non-default font in Android web app?

Tags: android, android-webview

I m developing mobile web application for Android OS. Here, my requirement is to use "Thoma" font, which is not default for desktop browsers and Android SDK webkit? Can you please help me how to use non-default font in web app in Mobile app, specifically in Android OS

Thanks in Advance - sri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the font you want to /assets/fonts folder (create the folders if you don't have them, most probably you don't).

Use something like this in your activity:

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/ARLRDBD.TTF");
titleBarText.setTypeface(tf);
```

In my case the font is Arial Bold.